# any way to recover a corrupt access 2007 database?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, corruption, repair

I've an access 2007 database which I been working on for a while which has now become corrupted somehow. When opening certain forms which contained VBA code I get the message "there isn't enough memory to perform this operation". There is no way to view any of the VBA at all. I've tried repair and compacts, disabling auto correct, decompiling and nothing works.

Anyone have any special ways to recover my lost forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, when none of the usual remedies work, I just create a new/blank Access database and import all the objects from the database that's having a problem. I can recall needing to do this 3 or 4 times in the last 10 years. Unfortunately, it's a hassle.